# How can i get file directory path on browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have input tag with type="file" and I want to show Directory of file that i uploaded from pc
a read an article that said you can get directory of file on system by security resone, but are they any solutions to solve that?
for example I want to get path like this :

***C:\Users\Windows 10\Downloads\Video\file.name***

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot access, or even read, the directory structure of the client PC through client-side Javascript. This has been a security feature of modern browsers for at least 5 years, probably nearer to 10.

There may be certain flags which can be enabled in specific browsers, but this is not a reliable solution as it requires the user to lower their security settings, and also is not consistent across all browsers.

The article which stated that you can do this is either outdated, or inaccurate.

Comment: Why can you set the download default folder for your Google Chrome? Why Jupyter notebook lets you decide where to download your files using your browser?

Comment: @Ivan those examples are not the same issue as above. That is to do with downloading a file, where the user is forced to choose a location by their **browser**. The question above is asking how to set the value of a file input **programmatically** via JS.